# mongo shell show collections returns empty list

Tags: mongodb

I use mongo shell and server version 3.2.10
show dbs command works as expected. When I switch to any of my dbs, the show collections command does nothing. I tried with db.getCollectionNames() and I receive an empty array [].
Using a tool like Robomongo shows my collections when I execute these commands.
Am I doing somthing wrong?

Comment: You sure the connection is OK, do you have more connections?

Comment: No more connections. Only the shell command windows is opened.

Comment: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-16361 try this it may help

Answer (score 11):

I found my problem.
I forgot that the database names are case senzitive. Using my database with capitalized first letter fixed the problem. Thank you anyway.